# How to check if a Javascript object contains an array as a value for an attribute?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, handlebars.js

I have an object coming from the form data (in javascript using express handlebars), which can be as one of the following:

```
object1 = { name: "Grade1", section: "A", courses: [ "Eng", "Math", "Sci"] }
```

OR

```
object2 = { name: "Grade1", section: "A", courses: "Sci" }
```

How can I determine whether the `courses` attribute contains an array or a single value?
Or is there a way to send the data from the form as an array for the attribute `courses` always (even if it is a single course)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `isArray` method. Note the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) which explains why you may want to use this method as opposed to `instanceOf`:

> When checking for `Array` instance, `Array.isArray` is preferred over `instanceof` because it works through `iframes`.

You may prefer this depending on your use case (assuming you're working with a browser) and gives you an opportunity to send it as an array if it isn't one already. Something like:

```
var object1 = { name: "Grade1", section: "A", courses: [ "Eng", "Math", "Sci"] };
var object2 = { name: "Grade1", section: "A", courses: "Sci" };

console.log(object2.courses);

if (!Array.isArray(object2.courses)) {
    object2.courses = [object2.courses];
 }

 console.log(object2.courses);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `instanceof` or `typeof` operator:

**To check if its an array:**

```
if (object.courses instanceof Array) {
  ···
}
```

**To check if its a string:**

```
if (typeof object.courses === 'string') {
  ···
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `typeof` to check if `object1.courses` is an array or a string.

There are ways of making sure courses is always an array when you receive the data.